# My navigation menu disappears when in mobile mode

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive, divi-theme

I am building a site using WordPress, a divi theme, and a windows operating system (if that matters). On desktop, my website looks fine but when I shrink the window or when I access the website on a mobile device, the navigation window at the top of the site seems to disappear.
Link to the website: [assyrians.com](https://assyrians.com)

What I tried: I thought maybe the plugins were the problem and tried deactivating my plugins but nothing changed. The divi theme is currently on Version 3.19.14, not exactly the newest version, which is 4:18 but I don't think updating the theme is the reason why this is happening.

I open to any suggestions and appreciate any feedback, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navigation bar is there, but when the viewport is mobile it turns into a hamburger menu, actually you cannot see it because the button has a blank color just as the background. Try adding the following css to your page and you will see the menu.

```
.mobile_menu_bar:before {
   color: red !important;
}
```

Or better try to edit the navigation menu with the divi builder customizer, select the phone preview and make your changes.

Divi documentation:

https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/divi/customizer-mobile/

Comment: Thank you! I made the changes through the customizer and it worked, I can see the menu.